# Changing iframe source depending on viewport width

Tags: jquery, iframe, responsive-design

I'm trying to get an `iframe` to change its source - from a full-sized version of a document to a mobile version - when the viewport width changes, using jQuery. Here's my current code:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            // on full-sized viewports
            if((document).width >= 1000) {
                // this line should change the src attribute
                $("#myIframe").attr('src', 'http://www.fullsize.url');

                // this just resizes the iframe
                $("#myIframe").width = 1000;
                $("#myIframe").height = 1200;
            }

            // on mobile viewports
            else {
                $("#myIframe").attr('src', 'http://www.mobilesize.url');
                $("#myIframe").width = 640;
                $("#myIframe").height = 800;
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe id="myIframe" src="http://www.fullsize.url">
</body>
```

The issue I'm having is that the new `src`, `width`, and `height` attributes don't actually update -- and I'm not sure why.

Is something like this even possible using jQuery, considering that this would require loading a new `iframe`? Do I need to do a workaround using Ajax to avoid having to reload the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$("#myIframe").width(value)` and `$("#myIframe").height(value)`

Edit : and replace `(document).width` with `$(window).width()`

Comment: Alright, that solves part of the question, so thanks - but what about `src`?

Comment: Your function is executed once, when the document is ready. If you want the `src` to be updated with the resizing of the window, you should handle the `resize` event